# InfoWindows in Nested Polygons (Google Maps Api 3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geoprocessing, google-maps-api

I have a large polygon with thick borders inside which there are several smaller polygons something like multiple city polygons inside a state border. The problem with this is that the info-windows for some of the polygons don't show up when i click the polygon.(i have set up a click listener for each smaller polygon)